# Read values of array in objects within objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I am making a report in which user read data from xml and push the data.

I am having a problem while maping the dataset of values readed from xml. Right now I am creating a object **deMapping** , in which there will be different sources like RBSK i have mentioned in the code.From RBSK it will read all the tags present in xml like *Childhood_Diseases_0_6_Female* and now i have mapped particular dataelemt and category on server side where we want to push data .
Like for (xmlid , dataelement,categoryOptionCombo). Its a long array **des[]**

Now on click of button I am calling the function preparedataset. In this I want to push values from xml to the set I am creating but here I want to push specific xmlid value and dataelement and category defined above in deMapping. But according to the following function It takes only last value of array des[] as resObj[prop] and I want to push all values mapped like above. Can anybody tell me the way? 
main part is the for loop in calling function.

```js
function prepareDataValueSet() {
    var deMapping = {
        RBSK: {
            'dsUID': 'tdTwLUxcQ8R', rootNodeName: 'RBSK_GIS_Indicator', orgUnitTagName: 'MCTSCode', des: [
                {
                    xmlid: "Childhood_Diseases_0_6_Female",
                    dataElement: "oV163sbcJ0N",
                    categoryOptionCombo: "Cmzbo9LD8pJ"
                },
                {
                    xmlid: "Childhood_Diseases_0_6_Male",
                    dataElement: "oV163sbcJ0N",
                    categoryOptionCombo: "PnAVAPG4yvb"
                },
                {
                    xmlid: "Childhood_Diseases_7_18_Female",
                    dataElement: "cEPledgs7rd",
                    categoryOptionCombo: "Cmzbo9LD8pJ"
                },
                {
                    xmlid: "Childhood_Diseases_7_18_Male",
                    dataElement: "cEPledgs7rd",
                    categoryOptionCombo: "PnAVAPG4yvb"
                },
                { xmlid: "Deficiencies_0_6_Female", dataElement: "gKupqkIhW4n", categoryOptionCombo: "Cmzbo9LD8pJ" },
                { xmlid: "Deficiencies_0_6_Male", dataElement: "gKupqkIhW4n", categoryOptionCombo: "PnAVAPG4yvb" },
                { xmlid: "Deficiencies_7_18_Female", dataElement: "FuEnn0bLuoT", categoryOptionCombo: "Cmzbo9LD8pJ" },
                { xmlid: "Deficiencies_7_18_Male", dataElement: "FuEnn0bLuoT", categoryOptionCombo: "PnAVAPG4yvb" },
                {
                    xmlid: "Developmental_dealy_and_disability_0_6_Female",
                    dataElement: "v37HBq7C72j",
                    categoryOptionCombo: "Cmzbo9LD8pJ"
                },
                {
                    xmlid: "Developmental_dealy_and_disability_0_6_Male",
                    dataElement: "v37HBq7C72j",
                    categoryOptionCombo: "PnAVAPG4yvb"
                },
                {
                    xmlid: "Developmental_dealy_and_disability_7_18_Female",
                    dataElement: "S1WMlAKnF8Z",
                    categoryOptionCombo: "Cmzbo9LD8pJ"
                },
                {
                    xmlid: "Developmental_dealy_and_disability_7_18_Male",
                    dataElement: "S1WMlAKnF8Z",
                    categoryOptionCombo: "PnAVAPG4yvb"
                },
                {
                    xmlid: "defect_at_birth_0_6_Female",
                    dataElement: "JJO3utHjb3l",
                    categoryOptionCombo: "Cmzbo9LD8pJ"
                },
                { xmlid: "defect_at_birth_0_6_Male", dataElement: "JJO3utHjb3l", categoryOptionCombo: "PnAVAPG4yvb" },
                {
                    xmlid: "defect_at_birth_7_18_Female",
                    dataElement: "qoVmtykHboz",
                    categoryOptionCombo: "Cmzbo9LD8pJ"
                },
                { xmlid: "defect_at_birth_7_18_Male", dataElement: "qoVmtykHboz", categoryOptionCombo: "PnAVAPG4yvb" }
            ]
        }
    }

    var dataValueSet = {};
    var dataValues = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < mstc.length; i++) {
        if (map[mstc[i]] == undefined) {
            msg += "," + +mstc[i];
            console.log(msg);
        }
        else if (dmap[map[mstc[i]]] != undefined) {
            for (var prop in deMapping) {
                var source = deMapping[prop];       //Source=RBSK
                for (var dataset in source) {
                    if (dataset === "des") {
                        source[dataset].forEach(function (resObj) {

                            for (var prop in resObj) {
                                console.debug(prop, ":", resObj[prop]);
                                var dataValue = {};
                                dataValue["period"] = "201509";
                                dataValue["dataElement"] = resObj[prop];
                                dataValue["categoryOptionCombo"] = 'resObj[prop]';
                                dataValue["value"] = mapDataValue[mstc[i] + ":" + 'resObj[prop]'];
                            }

                            dataValues.push(dataValue);
                            dataValueSet.dataValues = dataValues;
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(dataValueSet));
```

Comment: Please reduce the code to the absolute minimum to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Complex questions require precision of explanation. The first sentence explaining what you're doing doesn't really explain what you're doing coherently, leaving us hanging. You reference "dataelemt", I assume you mean dataElement? You refer to properties in a case insensitive manner. You refer to the "preparedataset" function when I assume you mean "prepareDataValueSet". Add in word errors like "readed" and by the time I put the puzzle together of what you're trying to communicate I've lost my train of thought solving it. Please rewrite for us & take a bit of time to be coherent and accurate.